# Why is the actual length of Galus Mitzraim not mentioned in the Torah?

Tags: midrash, time, yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt, golus-exile

Chazal expound that the Jews were in Mitzraim for 210 years (see Rashi to Bereishis 42:2, and to Avodah Zarah 9a). Why is this figure mentioned nowhere explicitly, especially when other numbers are (see, for instance, Bereishis 15:13 and Shemos 12:41)?

Comment: Why is this at all surprising? Many Midrashic details aren't in the text. Probably even the vast majority. Please [edit] your post to better motivate this and explain why this is different from any other detail mentioned by Chazal.

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course, but this seems like a pretty big thing that it left out - especially in light of the fact that it gave an entirely different number (430) that could have been the accurate one if not for that Midrash.

Comment: (It might still be the accurate one in spite of the Midrash...) Plenty of other details are important to the story or seem to clash with the simple meaning of the text. In any event, you should edit your question to better motivate it, whatever that motivation is.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75610/759

Comment: Seems strange to ask this question here when the answer referenced by @Double, written by you, answers the question you ask here.

Comment: @user6591 It's fine to ask questions even if you know the answer https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/307/759 though it's important when doing so not to "skimp on quality" and "write all questions from the point of view of someone who doesn't know an answer"