# How many years between the birth of Yosef and Moses?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, yosef, exodus

According to the Torah, how many years between the birth of Yosef and the birth of Moses?

Answer (score 5):

According to Seder Hadorot,

- Moses was born in the [year 2368 to creation](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24645&st=&pgnum=71).
- Joseph was born in the [year 2199 to creation](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24645&st=&pgnum=57).

2368-2199 = 169 years.

Note that Joseph was born in the summer (27th of Tammuz), while Moses was born at the end of the winter (7th Adar), so 168.5 years might be a bit more accurate.

Comment: thanx ........nic

Comment: @ميخائيلمينا do not neglect to accept answers please :)

Comment: @ Rabbi Kaii. I love all your answers, and appreciate them greatly.

Comment: @ميخائيلمينا thank you. I was speaking more generally, for example this question appears to have two acceptable answers?

Answer (score 2):

Joseph was 30 years old when he stood before Pharaoh (Genesis 41:46).

Joseph revealed himself and invited Jacob and his family to come to Egypt in the second year of the famine (Genesis 45:6) which would be approximately 9 years later (7 years of plenty plus 2 years of famine).

Moses was 80 when he stood before Pharaoh and initiated the plagues that culminated in the Exodus (Exodus 7:7).

Thus, we can write an equation “39 + X - 80 = Y”, where X is the total years the Israelites spent in Egypt and Y is the number of years between Joseph’s birth and Moses’s birth.

The value of X is [subject to dispute among the commentaries](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75610/how-long-was-the-period-of-oppression/98390#98390), but the most popular view is that it was 210 years. If we go with that we would solve the equation as 39 + 210 - 80 = 169.